# JavaScript form validation custom messages and minimum field length

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to use JavaScript to validate input of a simple form. There are three fields:

- **Name** is a required text field, cannot be empty
- **Email** is a required email field which must be from the domain *domain.com.au*
- **Postcode** is a required numeric field which must be 4 characters long

I would also like to have custom error messages displayed to the right of the fields rather than have the system popups appear.

At the moment the first two fields are validated correctly but the custom messages are not displayed. The postcode field does not validate apart from having to have at least one number in it.

JavaScript beginner here, please be kind.

```js
function validation() {
  var emailPattern = new RegExp('\w.%+-]+@domain\.com\.au');

  if (document.getElementById("name").value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("nameAlert").innerHTML = "<em> Please enter name here</em>";
    return false;
  } else if (emailPattern.test(document.getElementById("email").value) = false) {
    document.getElementById("emailAlert").innerHTML = "<em> Your email must include @domain.com.au </em>";
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById("postcode").value.length != 4) {
    document.getElementById("postcodeAlert").innerHTML = "<em> Your postcode must be four characters long </em>";
    return false;
  } else return true;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><span id="nameAlert"></span><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" pattern="[\w.%+-]+@domain\.com\.au"><span id="emailAlert"></span><br><br>
  <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
  <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" pattern="^[0-9]{4}"><span id="postcodeAlert"></span><br><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit Query</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note `</inpt>`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that - still not working though

Comment: There are no closing tags for `input` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Janiszewski, I have removed them but no joy

Comment: For all I see the message is displayed. Try removing `reuquired` from `input` tag and you will see, that your javascript code is working. Also, I do not think that `type="number"` is a good solution for postcode.

Comment: Thanks, I removed all the required tags and now the custom message displays for the name field but not the others. Postcode field length validation seems to work for type text but not type numeric, so I have changed the RegExp pattern to "^[0-9]{4}" and it now works! Now if only I could get custom messages for the last two fields.

Comment: When you identify problems described in *comments*, please edit your question so people can see where you're at right now, so that the next problem can be identified/answered easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have if statement and the else. So if first condition is true, others will not be checked, hence only one message displays.

**Here is a working example**

```js
function validation() {
  var emailPattern = new RegExp('\w.%+-]+@domain\.com\.au');
  var isOk = true;

  if (document.getElementById("name").value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("nameAlert").innerHTML = "<em> Please enter name here</em>";
    isOk = false;
  }

  if (emailPattern.test(document.getElementById("email").value) == false) {
    document.getElementById("emailAlert").innerHTML = "<em> Your email must include @domain.com.au </em>";
    isOk = false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("postcode").value.length != 4) {
    document.getElementById("postcodeAlert").innerHTML = "<em> Your postcode must be four characters long </em>";
    isOk = false;
  }

  return isOk;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><span id="nameAlert"></span><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" pattern="[\w.%+-]+@domain\.com\.au"><span id="emailAlert"></span><br><br>
  <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
  <input type="number" name="postcode" id="postcode" pattern="^[0-9]{4}"><span id="postcodeAlert"></span><br><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit Query</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, you have saved me a lot more frustration!